# Adding multiple fields to SQLite3 in a single Django migration

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, sqlite, migration

I have a SQLite3 table with ~2 million rows and ~30 columns. I need to add 4 more fields to the model. I add new fields to `models.py`, run `manage.py makemigrations` and then `manage.py migrate`. When I check SQL queries, Django creates a new table (and drops the old one) for each new field instead of creating a new table once with all 4 fields added. This increases migration time 4 times which results in ~1 hour. Is it possible to optimize this somehow and force Django to add all 4 fields in a single `CREATE TABLE` statement?

---

My current migration file:

```
from django.db import migrations, models

class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('my_project', '0017_auto_20200218_1325'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='ads',
            name='type',
            field=models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True),
        ),
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='my_project',
            name='color',
            field=models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True),
        ),
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='my_project',
            name='damage',
            field=models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True),
        ),
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='my_project',
            name='euro',
            field=models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True),
        )
    ]
```

Comment: How many migration files does the command `makemigrations` generate ?
1 or 4 ?

Comment: @Ibris 1 file with 4 AddField operations

Comment: Can you share it so that we can maybe determine what we could do? If there were 4 files I would have suggested to combine them into 1.
I know it is possible to write custom migrations scripts. Maybe we can customize the auto-generated one.

Comment: @Ibris I added migration file to the original question

Comment: It seems that [AddField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/migration-operations/#addfield) doesn't allow to add multiple fields in one query.
But like I said, you can write your own migration code.
See [HERE](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/migration-operations/#special-operations), where you can do special things [on your own](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/migration-operations/#writing-your-own).

Answer (score 1):

"Using Django ORM is not suited for real database operations. Sure, it might look okay(ish) when you are only performing basic CRUD operations. But it will force you to perform database queries in the least optimized way (see N+1 SELECT issue)…

Its syntax is inconsistent, and its lack of support for many SQL features (including JOIN) will make you go back to raw SQL queries as soon as things get tricky. Going back to raw SQL feels a bit like a failure when you are using an ORM, plus it is not easy to maintain." ---[Why wouldn’t we use Django ORM?](https://rodic.fr/blog/sqlalchemy-django/)

You can check [databse migration tool](https://alembic.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/index.html)

that can help u run in a single statement

```
def upgrade():
    op.create_table(
    'account',
    sa.Column('id', sa.Integer, primary_key=True),
    sa.Column('name', sa.String(50), nullable=False),
    sa.Column('description', sa.Unicode(200)),
)

def downgrade():
    op.drop_table('account')
```